Wedderburn Artin's theorem for algebras over a field
I learned about the Wedderburn Artin's theorem for simple left artinian ring, says that if $R$ is simple left Artinian ring then $R\cong\mathrm{M}_n(\Delta)$, for some division ring $\Delta$.
I want to use this result to prove the Wedderburn Artin's theorem for algebras over a field:
F is a field, A is finite dimensional simple $F$-algebra, then $A\cong\mathrm{M}_n(\Delta)$, for some finite dimensional division $F$-algebra $\Delta$.
I already prove that A is a left simple Artinian ring, thus by the Wedderburn Artin's theorem for simple left artinian ring, $A\cong\mathrm{M}_n(\Delta)$ for some division ring $\Delta$.
Problem

how can I prove that $\Delta$ is division algebra over ''$F$''.
If 1. is correct, then do I finish the proof of the Wedderburn Artin's theorem for algebras over a field or not (The point I confuse is that I use the Wedderburn Artin's theorem for simple left artinian ring, so the isomorphism is as ring but not algebra)

Thanks for your help!
